# Why does my Unity screen get corrupted

Tags: unity, screen-corruption

I recently installed 14.04 and noticed that after some use, the text and/or icons get corrupted.  I updated to 15.04 but the problem persists.

If I restart unity the problem goes away, but so do all my open windows.

I have an integrated Intel G33 GPU, running 64-bit Ubuntu 15.04 on an Intel Core 2 Duo, with 3GB RAM, Gallium 0.4 on i915 (chipset: G33)

Is there any way to fix this properly?

I've tried updating drivers through https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers